# Plugin to modify windows shortcut / functionality, to automate AD login

Tags: javascript, windows, dll, active-directory

I need to automate AD (Active directory) login and for this I need to modify windows functionality to ask for a server's password instead of system password.

**cntrl + Alt + Del**, which generally asks for system Login credentials, I want it to ask for my server's (say abc.com) Login Password.

when user will click or select,  control + Alt + Del, a box will appear asking for my server's password, and on click of submit, a call will be sent to abc's server.

Server will verify the entered password and if its correct it will return AD Password, then with this password I need to Authenticate the AD user.

So, I have 2 passwords (server password and AD password) and the steps are

1. enter server password
2. If server password is correct, server will return AD password
3. Authenticate and login user on windows with the AD Password which server returned.

I need to design a plugin for this, which when installed on any windows will work like this.

but I have no Idea yet, where to start with.
I have gone through few articles where I found there is **MSGina.dll** , but it is outdated and we have **custom credential providers** for this.
I am not sure how to use them.I generally work in JavaScript and nodejs, but I think this will need C/C++.

Please suggest me a way around.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: @user5821368 any update on this? struck with the same problem, Don't know where to start. any help would be appreciated

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM first of all sorry for the late reply. I have used pGina for this work, and its easy to use then anyother way.

Comment: http://mutonufoai.github.io/pgina/

Comment: @user5821368 I'm using SampleV2CredentialProvider, in that I can only get LOCAL users. any idea how to get AD users?